# Azure Functions deployment fail with torch

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions

The deployment of my python Azure Functions to Azure failed with `torch`. When I removed the `torch` from the `requirements.txt` the function could be deployed. I have tried with both VS code azure functions extension and Azure CLI and they gave the same result. My testing `requirments.txt` is:

```
azure-functions

--find-links=https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
torch>1.5,<1.8
```

It prompts `/opt/Kudu/Scripts/starter.sh oryx build /tmp/zipdeploy/extracted -o /home/site/wwwroot --platform python --platform-version 3.8 -p packagedir=.python_packages/lib/site-packages` and then `Deployment failed.`

The functions works as expected when being deployed to localhost. I am using python 3.8.6 in Mac OSX mojave.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem is solved by simply changing the dependency to

```
torch==TORCH_VERSION+cpu
```

I read this [article](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/apps-on-azure/why-use-azure-functions-for-ml-inference/ba-p/1416728) which mentioned that `GPU support is not available` in Azure functions. So, I guess only the dependency to `CPU-only torch` can be properly installed.